# Android Firebase Retrieving Data Synchronized and "returning" it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm sorry if this may seem like a stupid question, but I haven't found any similar questions around so here goes.

I have a class DatabaseService for retrieving data(Animal) from the Firebase Realtime-Database. From a previous post I've learned that because these API calls are asynchronous, one should create an Interface in order to sync the retrieval of data ( the onDataChange() method )

My questions are:

1. why does creating this interface and passing it as a parameter work for synchronizing data retrieval? In my code , why does calling the interfaces' method onCallBack (which isn't even defined until later) make it happen, what are the steps that take place to make it happen?
2. Having created this class as a database service (hence the name), I want it to return a list of animals ( List ) for the Activity that containts this service, MyAnimalsActivity , in order to make a RecyclerView. Is there any way I can change the "void" in this Interface method to "List" to have something like

   ```
   List<Animal> listAnimals = databaseService.readData();
   ```

   or should this entire DatabaseService class rather be removed and
   add its' code in the MyAnimalsActivity itself, in order to add the Animals Objects inside a global list in the onDataChange() method?

DatabaseService:

```
public class DatabaseService {

    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference firebaseRootRef;
    private DatabaseReference animalsRef;
    List<Animal> animalsList;

    public DatabaseService() {

        this.firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        this.firebaseRootRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        this.animalsRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("animals");

        animalsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    private interface FirebaseCallback {
        void onCallback(List<Animal> list);
    }

    public void readItemsFromDatabase(final FirebaseCallback firebaseCallback) {

        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                animalsList.clear();

                //dataSnapshot.getChildren() ---> iterate through entire dataSnapshot Object, to get the items names
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Animal animal;
                    animal = ds.getValue(Animal.class);
                    animalsList.add(animal);
                }

                firebaseCallback.onCallback(animalsList);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("DATABASE_TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };

        animalsRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

    }


    public void readData() {
        readItemsFromDatabase(new FirebaseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(List<Animal> list) {
                Log.d("DATABASE_TAG", list.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MyAnimalsActivity :

```
public class MyAnimalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter animalAdapter;

private List<Animal> listAnimals;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_animals);

    DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();
    databaseService.readData();


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); //every item of the recyclerview has a fixed size;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    listAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
    //listAnimals  =  databaseService.readData();  ??


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a method that returns an asynchronous value that might be not there can cause NullPointers if you call it before it has the data.

To make this simple, since the method `readItemsFromDatabase` is public, you can call it from your `MyAnimalsActivity` and get your data from there.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_animals);

    DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();
    databaseService.readItemsFromDatabase(new DatabaseService.FirebaseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(List<Animal> list) {
                Log.d("DATABASE_TAG", list.toString());

            }
        });
...
```

I have isolated your issue with a project of mine and it's working; also, you can check the MVP pattern that will solve all these issues for you and your code will become cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, but after writing it as you suggested, the Database method "onCallBack" isn't synchronized anymore. Is there anything specific I should do? 
http://prntscr.com/mqpd61

Comment: From what I understand, the readItemsFromDatabase(..) is still not synchronized, so what I've done to fix it is move the relevant code (a RecyclerView for instance) inside it's onCallBack method.

Comment: Yes, you will need to move that inside the callback because you don't know when it will finish

Comment: Your list will be set at anytime the callback ends , so you can't guarantee you have your list filled with the data at the start of the Activity